# typedef Foo<> Foo compiles but is it valid?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

The following bit of code compiles in VS2008 and GCC 4.8.2

```
template<typename T=void>
struct Foo
{
};

// typedef Foo<> Foo;   // Does *NOT* compile

int main()
{
    typedef Foo<> Foo;
    Foo f1;

   // Foo<char> f2;     // Does *NOT* compile
   //::Foo<char> f3;    // COMPILES
}
```

Is it valid?

Comment: You're providing default arguments in the template. It's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Captain: But what about the fact that they're both named `Foo`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per C++11 3.3.10/1:

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a **nested declarative region** or derived
>   class.

(Emphasis mine)

That's why the template name `Foo` can be hidden by the typedef name `Foo` inside `main()` (a different scope), but not in the same scope as the template name is declared.

As to why this similar case is legal:

```
struct Foo
{
};

typedef Foo Foo;   // *DOES* compile
```

That is explicitly allowed by 7.1.3/3:

> In a given non-class scope, a `typedef` specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that
>   scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.

Comment: 3.3.1 [basic.scope.declarative]/p4 is also relevant.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it's valid, for the same reason that this is valid:

```
struct Foo { };

namespace bar {
    struct Foo { };
}
```

You're just overwriting the name in a different scope. Inside of main, you can still do something like:

```
::Foo<int> f2;
```

Comment: Ah, typename shadowing. How deliciously sneaky :O

Comment: I think this answer is not right - there is a template Foo replaced by a typedef (in one namespace)

Comment: @DieterLücking Why? I can just as easily in main create an `int Foo = 7;` It's just a name.

Comment: @DieterLücking It's in one namespace, but in a different scope.